# Visual Studio 2022 build failed - but showing no errors

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2022

The only strange thing is a warning on the projects, but without any indication of what it is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the Errors panel? What happens if you compile your project from the command line? Run `dotnet build -c Release` inside your project folder.

Comment: Try to clean your solution `right click on solution > Clean solution` the try to rebuild it should an error message appears in error panel

Comment: Clean the solution didn't help, but after building from the command line I found the error. A missing reference in a partial view. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Two suggestions. 

1. From the VS IDE's Tools|Options dialog, select the "Projects and Solutions \ Build and Run" properties page and set the MSBuild output and log verbosity to "Diagnostic" (the last 2 combos on that settings page). 

2. Build your solution from the command line using msbuild /bl <whateveryour solution is>, and then analyze the results in using the MSBuild Structured Log Viewer (msbuildlog.com)

Comment: i use suggestion one to see the errors in the MSBuild and i found errors in the views, thank you Ed Dore

Comment: this happened to me, I changed the Configuration to Release, then changed it back to Debug and all the errors disappeared. This might have been a coincidence.

Answer (score 90):

On error view, Change Show issues generated to "Build Only"

[image: Change Show issues generated]

Comment: This quick and easy fix made my day! Fantastic!

Comment: This seems like a workaround for bug in the IDE rather than an actual fix. It works, but it doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: How is it possible that Razor compilation gets worse with each VS release? Anyone else noticing that? Are they trying to send us the message to move to React or Blazor? I prefer straightforward communication rather than passive aggressively just making the software more frustrating and terrible. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: As others said, this works but the issue remains as a bug in VS. Blazor projects have the exact same problem given their use of Razor.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved a lot of my time. Thanks again. This worked for me like magic.

Comment: I've had this issue and I believe I resolved it by finding and deleting a `.sln.metaproj` that someone had checked into source control.

Answer (score 3):

Go to location of the project, delete .vs folder and re-build again.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, after switching between different git branches.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple projects under same solution make sure the Target Framework (Right click project -> properties) of each project is feasible for the referencing project. I was trying to refer to a project (v4.8) from v4.6 and encountered this error.

And also try checking the build order of the project (Right click solution -> Project Build Order) and clean and build each projects according to that order.

Comment: solution for me. Forgot one project to upgrade the .NET FW Version and build output did not point to this.

Comment: Solution for me, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Symantec Antivirus running on your machine, it could block MSBuild.exe from Visual Studio resulting in the build failing.

You may re-install/ reconfigure Symantec to allow MSBuild.exe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio Installer, click Modify on the version that's not working, select the Individual Components tab, untick Intellicode and click Modify (bottom right).

Once it's finished, go through the same process but tick it this time, restart VS (which you have to do anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem. None of the above answers worked for me.

So I tried the old **"turn it off and then back on again"** and it worked

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and run using ``` shift +`` ```   key in visual studio. Run `dotnet run` all errors will be shown on terminal